# AngularJS - Onde colocar funções de Jquery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Tenho algumas funções em jquery que normalmente seria em um arquivo .js mesmo, mas quando utilizo Angular onde deve colocar, seguindo as boas praticas?

Exemplo: Tenho uma função que determina se meu Header fique ou não ocultou dependendo do tamanho do scroll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não há nada na especificação do Angular que force a localização de um arquivo de recurso com funcionalidades extras.

Se você não está consumindo nada do Angular e o Angular não espera nada de você, deixe o código à parte mesmo.

Comment: Outra coisa, estou consumindo db então o correto seria colocar minhas funções no Controller?

Comment: @CharlesPresidente Isso dependerá principalmente da maneira como você está implementando a conexão entre a sua aplicação e o banco, mas em termos gerais acessos a recursos são centralizados em serviços/factories.